# How to run cordova music player in background with options available on notification bar

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am building music player application for android phone using cordova media plugin.

With the help of plugin i am able to play the local music now i wants to add a feature that even if the application is closed by the user. 
Music player should run in background with play,pause,exit options available in notification bar.

Can any one help me in this case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you figure out a solution to this yet?

Comment: https://github.com/homerours/cordova-music-controls-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this plugin here, and it works for me on android:
https://github.com/homerours/cordova-music-controls-plugin

It does not control the media for you automatically though, you have handle its events and control the media yourself.

Keep in mind that at the moment, if your app is closed in the background by the system, the notification will still be shown. This is a known bug.